System.IO.File.WriteAllText create corrupted file
I'm trying to automate a series of downloads from a website.
I can list the files and eventually download them, but it seems my code creates a corrupted file when saving it.
The filesize is accurate (it seems it writes anything as supposed) but the archive created is corrupted (zip file).
Public Class DownloadedData
    Public Property Data As Byte()
    Public Property Url As Uri
End Class

The class itself:
Public Class HelperWebClient

    Public Async Function DownloadDataAsync(ByVal nomeficheiro As String, ByVal bolachas As String, urls As List(Of String)) As Task(Of List(Of DownloadedData))

        Dim allTasks As List(Of Task) = New List(Of Task)
        Dim downloadedDataList As List(Of DownloadedData) = New List(Of DownloadedData)

        For i As Integer = 0 To urls.Count - 1
            'set value
            Dim url As Uri = New Uri(urls(i))
            Dim url2 As String = urls(i)
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0}]: Adding {1}", i, url))

            Dim t = Task.Run(Async Function()
                                 'create new instance
                                 Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()
                                 Const _Tls12 As SslProtocols = CType(&HC00, SslProtocols)
                                 Const Tls12 As SecurityProtocolType = CType(_Tls12, SecurityProtocolType)
                                 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12
                                 System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                                 wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
                                 wc.Headers.Add("Referer", url2)
                                 wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/ 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv: 79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0")
                                 wc.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
                                 wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5")
                                 wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br")
                                 wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, bolachas)

                                 'await download
                                 Dim result = Await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url)
                                 Debug.WriteLine(url2 & " download complete")

                                 'ToDo: add desired code
                                 'add
                                 downloadedDataList.Add(New DownloadedData() With {.Url = url, .Data = result(0)})
                                 Debug.WriteLine(result.ToString())
                             End Function)
            'add
            allTasks.Add(t)
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To allTasks.Count - 1
            'wait for a task to complete
            Dim t = Await Task.WhenAny(allTasks)

            'remove from List
            allTasks.Remove(t)

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(nomeficheiro, downloadedDataList(i).Data)

            Debug.WriteLine($"[{i}]: Filename: {nomeficheiro}")
        Next

        Debug.WriteLine("all tasks complete")

        Return downloadedDataList
    End Function
End Class

Note: The URL for download is dynamic, so I don't know the complete link to download. This way, I name the file myself with the following code (I know it downloads a .zip file):
Now I can't handle the following line:
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(nomeficheiro, downloadedDataList(i).Data)

I have an error like (under result):
value of type byte() cant be converted to string

Can anyone point me in the right direction to discover why the file is being created corrupted?

If it's a zip file, why are you downloading it as string? You get garbage there already, then you convert this already shredded data into UTF-8, double-destroying it.

@GSerg, since I'm creating a list with the downloads, how would I approach the tasks with DownloadDataTaskAsync? Obviously the downloadedDataList.Add(New DownloadedData() With {.Url = myUri, .Data = result}) will return me an error.

Make your DownloadedData expect a byte array rather than a string? Use DownloadFileTaskAsync and avoid the need of downloadedDataList altogether?

@GSerg, i've been able to do it with DownloadFileTaskAsync but it always tells me since it doesn't produce an output it will run synchronously. Can you please help me getting this asynchronously? Having a Public Async Function with only Await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(New Uri(url), nomeficheiro)  retrives: This method lacks Await operators.

@Tiago Does await WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync not working help?

@AndrewMorton, I've landed on that page and tried that, but it makes my UI unresponsive and files are always 0 bytes.

@Tiago Have you updated the DownloadedData class property Data to have a type of Byte()? It might be better to edit the question to add the latest state of the code.

@AndrewMorton, yes. I'm just having trouble handling the result as Byte. I've updated my code in main post.

@Tiago Based on the latest update to the question, you want the File.WriteAllBytes Method.

@AndrewMorton despiste using the wrong method, there must be something wrong since all files have 47.5KB.

@Tiago Is the data the same in all the files? You can use fc /b to check. Or use a hex editor to view them - you can use Visual Studio or something like HxD

@AndrewMorton, fc /b tells me that file 1 is longer than file 2. This means it's different, but keeps corrupted with the wrong filesize. It could be something about cookies/headers? What would be the way to check?

@Tiago Open the file in a hex editor and look at what is in there - and compare it to the correct file. You need to start thinking "Hmmm... why's that different?" ;)
